# Editing woocommerce order email confirmation

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, label, editing

I have a bot of an issue here with woocommerce email conformation. I am trying to edit all email labels in red.

[image: image of labels to be changed]

I managed to change some of the labels such as delivery address and billing address but cant find anywhere where to change these. Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a theme that provides Woocommerce integration?

Comment: Found what was the issue, I was using child theme which did not load "load_theme_textdomain", fixed that issue by redirecting main function to main theme folder.

Answer (score 0):

Found what was the issue, I was using child theme which did not load "load_theme_textdomain", fixed that issue by redirecting main function to main theme folder.